# How to make bottom sheet not fully hide when you close it?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.implementation.bottomsheet.BrowserBottomSheet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    />
```

When i close the bottom sheet,  i do not want it to hide completely, the top portion should be visible and can be used to pull it back up. is this possible?

Above view will be inside another layout

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. We can use `app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).